# Adding Spring Security starter to my Spring Boot app automatically redirects all paths to one that's set in a completely different project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I added Spring Security Starter dependency (I use Maven) to secure my app (following a tutorial); the problem is that once I add it, whenever I go to localhost to check my progress, I'm always redirected to a path that's coded in another project (I can't even find the view right now).

I currently follow the tutorial on [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/index.htm), but I use [Spring Tools Suite 4](https://spring.io/tools) for adding dependencies, coding and running my Spring application instead of CLI on localhost:8080.

I tried finding the view in question, tinkering with another project's web.xml, but I can't find the source of the problem, all I know is that Spring Security Starter is somehow mucking it up.

## Thymeleaf template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset = "ISO-8859-1" />
      <link href = "css/styles.css" rel = "stylesheet"/>
      <title>Spring Boot Application</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h4>Welcome to Thymeleaf Spring Boot web application</h4>
   </body>
</html>
```

## Web controller

```
package com.example.vj7.Controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class WebController {
   @RequestMapping(value = "/index")
   public String index() {
      return "index";
   }
}
```

## Application class

```
package com.example.vj7;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Vj7Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Vj7Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

## Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>vj7</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Vj7</name>
    <description>Vježba 7</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The expected result from "localhost:8080" is just a header "Demo" (like in index.html and set in web controller), but instead a form I worked on before on another Spring project shows up with path "/login".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override some of web security's default configurations if you want `index.html` to be accessed without authorization. taken from https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableWebSecurity.html

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebSecurity
 public class MyWebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/index").permitAll().anyRequest()
                                .permitAll();
        }
 }
```